# PHP dirname() loses last folder

Tags: file, path, explode, dirname

### The Problem

This is a very simple-to-understand question.

I'm having a user submit a URL, for example "http://example.com/path/filename.html".

I'm using PHP's `dirname()` function to get the so-called "base" of this URL. For the above example, that would be "http://example.com/path".

My problem arises when the user enters this:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

If you type the above into your browser, you will see the index.php or .html page in the folder called "blog". However, PHP's `dirname()` will return only "http://example.com".

I'm not sure if it thinks that "blog" is an extension-less file, if that exists, but I can't really find a solution.

### Things I've Tried

I first tried getting the extension of the URL using this quick method:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php';
$file_extension = end(explode('.', $filename));
```

Then, I would check if the extension existed using PHP `empty()`. If the extension exists, that means that a filename was entered after the folder, such as "http://example.com/path/file.html", and `dirname()` is perfect. If the extension doesn't exist, no file was entered and the last item in the path is a folder, so it is already "the base".

However, in the case of simply "http://example.com/path/", the above would return ".com/path/" as the file extension, which we all know doesn't exist. In this case, I would use the `dirname()` function and cut off "/path/".

EDIT:

Taking the extension of `basename($url)` won't work because if the user enters "http://example.com" `basename()` returns "example.com", the extension for which is supposedly 
".com"

#### Hopefully, someone has had the same problem and knows the solution. I'm still looking, but any answers are wholly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Ok, last time before I give up:

```
function getPath($url){
    $parts=explode("/",$url);
    $patharray=array(".","http:","https:");
    if(!in_array(pathinfo($url,PATHINFO_DIRNAME),$patharray) && strpos($parts[count($parts)-1], ".")!==false)
        unset($parts[count($parts)-1]);
    $url=implode("/",$parts);
    if(substr($url,-1)!='/')
        $url.="/";
    return $url;
}
echo getPath("http://www.google.com/blog/testing.php")."\n";
echo getPath("www.google.com/blog/testing.php")."\n";
echo getPath("http://www.google.com/blog/")."\n";
echo getPath("http://www.google.com/blog")."\n";
echo getPath("http://www.google.com")."\n";
echo getPath("http://www.google.com/")."\n";
echo getPath("www.google.com/")."\n";
echo getPath("www.google.com")."\n";
```

Any url with the last portion having a "." in it is parsed out, otherwise it is left alone.  It uses `pathinfo()` to check to see if it is just a domain ("google.com" or "http://www.google.com") and then leaves the last portion alone as there would be a "." in it.
Here is the script output:

```
http://www.google.com/blog/
www.google.com/blog/
http://www.google.com/blog/
http://www.google.com/blog/
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/
www.google.com/
www.google.com/
```

Comment: Looks good, but when I tried the bottommost code it included "index.html" in `$parsed['path']`. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @apparatix Fixed it.  Sorry it didn't work, this does and was tested.

Comment: Sorry to reject you again, but using "http://example.com/blog" will return only the domain without "blog". Although I agree with putting the "/" after `dirname`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for trying haha. Tried it out, works great. I noticed that using a domain without trailing slash, e.g. "http://example.com" gets the "example.com" cut off. Adding the trailing slash, however, fixes the problem. Thanks!